# PDFBOX java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space; GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I am working on a Java project.
I retrieve pdf from a server and convert it into images to compare pixels with the expected files. 
The program is fine when I only run it with 20-30 files, but it throws me OutOfMemoryError when I try to use more than 30 files.

It seems like the pdf -> image conversion method is producing the OutOfMemoryError.

Here is the method:

```
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFile), null);
        List<PDPage> pages = new ArrayList<PDPage>();
        for (Object obj : document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) (obj);
            pages.add(page);
        }
        int pageNum = 0;
        for (PDPage pdPage : pages) {
            BufferedImage img = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 100);
            if (isExpected) {
                ImageIOUtil.writeImage(img, FolderUtils.getImageFolder(websiteName) + File.separator + "expected"
                        + (++pageNum) + ".png", 100);
            } else {
                ImageIOUtil.writeImage(img, FolderUtils.getImageFolder(websiteName) + File.separator + "rendered"
                        + (++pageNum) + ".png", 100);
            }
            img.flush();
            img = null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        debugLog.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            try {
                document.close();
                document = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                debugLog.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the part of the log for Java Heap Space:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:340)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.CompositeImage.createMaskedImage(CompositeImage.java:85)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage.applyMasks(PDXObjectImage.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap.getRGBImage(PDPixelMap.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.Invoke.process(Invoke.java:87)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
    at ********************.convertPDFToImages(Processor.java:107)
    at ********************.APIProcessor.run(APIProcessor.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the part of log for GC overhead limit exceed:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Collections.singletonList(Collections.java:3349)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parseDictObjects(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:1275)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.initialParse(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:414)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parse(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:886)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.loadNonSeq(PDDocument.java:1273)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.loadNonSeq(PDDocument.java:1256)
    at *********************.convertPDFToImages(Processor.java:99)
    at ********************.APIProcessor.run(APIProcessor.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also, the first Java heap space error occurred at id22, and the second one is at id33. 
I am using 8GB RAM on server with `MAVEN_OPTS=-d64 -Xms500M -Xmx7000M -XX:PermSize=65M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Temp\heapDump.txt -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8123,server=y,suspend=n`

May I ask for some help on what is wrong with my code? Or what is causing the problem here? Is there a memory leak?

P.S.: Here is the link to the rendered pdf file and screen shots of JConsole:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/86gxnmnk5gl66k6/AAAFE_lapBr3cH8EMlXu94qJa?dl=0

Also, I am now running the program on a 8GB RAM server. But if I run it on my 16GB RAM laptop locally, there is no java heap space error.

Comment: What version are you using? Hopefully 1.8.10?

Comment: I am using java 1.8.0_60 version.

Comment: What pdfbox version?

Comment: Should I upgrade the pdfbox to 1.8.10?

Comment: It's always best to use the latest release before asking a question. About your question - please try this: page.getResources().clear() after processing a page. Also remove this weird "pages.add(page)" part. getAllPages() already gives you a list.

Comment: Additionally, to be sure that this isn't a bug, test your software with the last file only.

Comment: Still gets the java heap space error.

Comment: if I run the program with only the file for ID22, it works. In fact, if I divide the files into 2 batch (around 25 each), the program works fun.

Comment: Tried upgrade to 1.8.10. And used page.getResources().clear(). Not working.

Comment: Could you change your software to run the "worst" file several times? Does it happen after several times? If yes, can you share the file? Or reproduce it with some non confidential file?

Comment: a workaround could be to create and use a scratchfile (see javadoc of loadNonSeq, also for RandomAccessFile (the class in PDFBox, not the one in java)). Altough I suspect that if the problem exists, then this trick would just postpone the out-of-memory.

Comment: Thank you for providing all the ideas!!!
If I run the same file for 50 times and the problem still exists. Does this mean the program has a memory leak?

Comment: The link to rendered pdf is included in the question at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks... I'm running your code on my (slow) PC with default settings. This will take some time. If I can reproduce the effect, then it would indeed be a memory leak.

Comment: I've now done 54 rounds with your file and it is still working. Maybe it is something else in your software? Or a JDK problem? Suggestion: subscribe on https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/ and post your code there (it should be complete, your code above uses stuff that doesn't exist, e.g. isExpected, FolderUtils). I do also see that you're doing multithreading. This is OK as long as each PDDocument object has its own thread.

Comment: The pdf to image conversion is the only place where a large chunk of memory is used. 
But i do not have the java heap error on my own laptop with 16GB ram. 
On the server, the ram is 8GB tho. Could that be one of the reason?

Comment: I don't think so. I have 8GB RAM too, but I use default java settings, but in JDK7. Yes, your files are huge. But I'm now at loop 68.

Comment: This means other stuff is filling up the heap space? Could this be a memory leaking situation?

Comment: I don't know. All I can tell is that it doesn't happen for me.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you so much for the help!
I updated the dropbox link with JConsole screen shots. 
Does the screen shot indicate a memory leak?

Comment: Not for me. But finding memory leaks is a difficult science anyway, and it isn't done with a few screenshots, that is why I suggested you ask this in the PDFBox mailing list, people have different JDKs so they could run different environments. Me, to find a memory leak, I would rather use a profiler (e.g. the one from netbeans) and look whether more and more objects remain. The problem is that using a profiler makes your program much slower. I have a memory leak problem in a 2.0 PDFBox preflight test program and I can't find it, because it can be experienced only after maybe 100000 files :-(

Comment: Thank you good sir!!! You were great help!!!

Answer (score -1):

We did have several problems with PDFBox image convertion as well. It does consume a lot of the heap space as it runs through the Buffered Images and is a time bomb as it increase the number of generated pages.

Our solution was change the library. We did get a good performance with JPedal, and, if things didn't change, they do have a LGPL version of their framework.

Comment: This isn't really a useful answer. It's like someone asking about a problem with his BMW, and getting the answer "Get a Mercedes". (Disclosure: I'm a PDFBox committer)